# Optimizing read-write operations in Settings class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Using `Properties.Settings.Default` is great to save UI settings. 
I can use get it directly from any class but can also style everything with it

```
FontSize="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, Path=MyFontSize, Mode=OneWay}"
```

I am afraid doing everything with is makes my program slow.

This piece of code takes about 500ms:

```
bool b;
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
  b = Properties.Settings.Default.testbool;
```

I don't know what kind of object this is but I am hoping there is a way to make something with similar properties but FASTER and I can save it to settings back at closing of program.

Comment: Reading from settings 100 000 times took half a second. How many settings do you have in your application to even start thinking that it could slow it down? We're talking of microseconds per setting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I do not recommend doing the following.

If you *really* wanted to improve the performance of this you could redirect the Settings class's indexer to read from a dictionary:

```
internal sealed partial class Settings
{
    private bool _isLoaded = false; 
    Dictionary<string, object> _tempValues = new Dictionary<string,object>();

    public override object this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (_isLoaded)
            {
                return _tempValues[propertyName];
            }
            else
            {
                return base[propertyName];
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if (_isLoaded)
            {
                _tempValues[propertyName] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                base[propertyName] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnSettingsLoaded(object sender, System.Configuration.SettingsLoadedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSettingsLoaded(sender, e);

        _isLoaded = true;

        foreach (SettingsProperty property in Properties)
        {
            _tempValues[property.Name] = base[property.Name];
        }
    }

    protected override void OnSettingsSaving(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (SettingsProperty property in Properties)
        {
            base[property.Name] = _tempValues[property.Name];
        }

        base.OnSettingsSaving(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Benchmark code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();

        bool c;

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            c = Properties.Settings.Default.MyBool;
        }

        timer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Time before: 1348ms

Time after: 101ms

Comment: I did not even know this was possible. I like these kind of answers that exceed expectations. Great idea! Thanks!